# I'm authenticating the frontend app, using cookies session, but how to authenticate a user using ReactJS + Springbot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, session-cookies

I have to authenticate users in a scenario that involve a frontend(react) and a backend (springboot).

After working on it I realized that Springboot response include a set-cookie header, but actually the cookie session returned by Springboot is never set in the user-browser, so I asssume the cookie is set in the frontend app, which means that basically the frontend-app is the one authenticated, but no the user, make sense because the frontend is in the end sending the user/password.

How the people approach this scenario usually?, should I have a cookie session as well in the user-browser (so far is my thought)?, should the frontend store something different in the browser to keep track of logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally I would go with Bearer token based authentication as I could use the backend for mobile applications as well.

Basically you would require to store the JWT in the local storage or key chain.

You could authenticate using JWT token. Get user details from token to use it in front end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the session token in the localStorage. After storing it in localStorage you need to check session token on every protected route. If it's same as you have in backend it's good to go. However, if it has expired you need to run your logout api.